# Joomla insists on replacing h1 tags in article

Tags: php, content-management-system, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

So i've read just about every single topic on the web concerning this, yet nothing seems to fix my issue.

I have been asked to replace h2 tags with h1 tags on a customers site as part of a SEO overhaul, but joomla insist on not doing this for some reason, whenever an article contains a  tag it "magically" gets replaced by a h2 when the article is rendered.

I've tried the much suggested override method in the template, with no luck so far and i've tried searching through all parts of the joomla source code looking for a function that replaces h1 with h2 so that i may get rid of it, with no luck.

So my question is, how can i get joomla to stop switching my h1 tags to h2 tags when they are put in an article? Where is this behavior defined and/or how do i override it and tell it to seize doing so?

The site is using joomla 2.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already? There is a lot of examples on how to do it on google, so it would be best if you showed what was tried and why it fails? Have you seen this : http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-change-h2-tags-to-h1-tags-in-the-articles-title-in-joomla

Comment: Have you tried turning off the WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: Sorry, kinda loosing my head here from frustration so forgot to add ;)

So far i've tried what is suggested in the article you are linking, along with trying to search through all the php files trying to find whatever code is reponsible for this behavior.

My problem is not so much the article titles, but <h1> tags used in an article seems to get transformed into <h2> tags when rendered.

Strixy: I have tried pressing toggle editor to verify that they show up as <h1> in the source, yes, not tried disabling it completely no

Comment: I've never heard of this happening in Joomla. If you edit an article and make them all h1 elements, save the article and then reopen it, do the articles contain h1 or h2 elements? This will determine if the editor is changing something, it isn't saving properly, or it is rendering wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 hours of searching back and forth i finally found out that the SEO plugin SH404 was to blame, apparently it comes with an option that rewrites all but one  to  tags, this option is on by default -.-

Thanks anyway

Comment: I didn't think that this sounded like a core Joomla feature. Glad you were able to track it down!